# Lenovo Thinkpad L15 20U8 Integrated Camera stops working sometimes

Tags: 20.04, lenovo, thinkpad, camera

On startup my camera is detected but after some time when I try to use it again its not found and even in the lsusb and lspci output the camera doesn't show up. I‘m running Ubuntu 20.4.1

Rebooting fixes it. camera is enabled in bios, my keyboard has no camera function key

After reboot:

```
$ lsusb

Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 8087:0029 Intel Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 5986:9106 Acer, Inc Integrated Camera
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 27c6:55b4 Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Fingerprint Reader
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 058f:9540 Alcor Micro Corp. AU9540 Smartcard Reader
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 25a7:fa67  
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 214b:7250  USB2.0 HUB
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
$ lspci

00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 51)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 7
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0e)
02:00.1 Serial controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 816a (rev 0e)
02:00.2 Serial controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 816b (rev 0e)
02:00.3 IPMI Interface: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 816c (rev 0e)
02:00.4 USB controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 816d (rev 0e)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a)
04:00.0 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. SD/MMC Card Reader Controller (rev 01)
06:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir (rev d1)
06:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 1637
06:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
06:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir USB 3.1
06:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir USB 3.1
06:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor (rev 01)
06:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
```

```
$ cat var/log/dmesg | grep video

 [    3.620983] kernel: videodev: Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[    3.643811] kernel: uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Integrated Camera (5986:9106)
[    3.671742] kernel: uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Integrated Camera (5986:9106)
[    3.681398] kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[    3.811838] kernel: thinkpad_acpi: This ThinkPad has standard ACPI backlight brightness control, supported by the ACPI video driver
[    5.534021] kernel: Modules linked in: nf_log_ipv6 ip6t_REJECT fjes(-) amd64_edac_mod(-) nf_reject_ipv6 xt_hl ip6t_rt nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg nf_log_ipv4 nf_log_common snd_hda_codec ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 snd_hda_core xt_LOG snd_hwdep amdgpu thinkpad_acpi snd_pcm nvram ledtrig_audio snd_seq_midi iwlmvm uvcvideo edac_mce_amd videobuf2_vmalloc snd_seq_midi_event videobuf2_memops iommu_v2 btusb mac80211 videobuf2_v4l2 gpu_sched videobuf2_common snd_rawmidi kvm_amd btrtl libarc4 ttm kvm btbcm btintel videodev drm_kms_helper xt_limit crct10dif_pclmul bluetooth ghash_clmulni_intel xt_addrtype mc cec snd_seq xt_tcpudp rc_core ecdh_generic joydev ecc i2c_algo_bit aesni_intel iwlwifi input_leds crypto_simd snd_seq_device fb_sys_fops snd_timer syscopyarea sysfillrect snd_rn_pci_acp3x efi_pstore cryptd serio_raw glue_helper snd_pci_acp3x wmi_bmof cfg80211 sysimgblt k10temp rapl ipmi_devintf snd ccp ipmi_msghandler
[    5.534105] kernel:  ucsi_acpi typec_ucsi soundcore typec mac_hid xt_conntrack nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 libcrc32c ip6table_filter ip6_tables sch_fq_codel iptable_filter parport_pc bpfilter ppdev lp drm parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic usbhid hid crc32_pclmul psmouse sdhci_pci cqhci nvme i2c_piix4 r8169 xhci_pci sdhci xhci_pci_renesas nvme_core realtek wmi video i2c_scmi
```

Some minutes later:

```
$ lsusb

Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 27c6:55b4 Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Fingerprint Reader
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 058f:9540 Alcor Micro Corp. AU9540 Smartcard Reader
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 25a7:fa67  
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 214b:7250  USB2.0 HUB
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
$ lspci

00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 51)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 7
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0e)
02:00.1 Serial controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 816a (rev 0e)
02:00.2 Serial controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 816b (rev 0e)
02:00.3 IPMI Interface: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 816c (rev 0e)
02:00.4 USB controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 816d (rev 0e)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a)
04:00.0 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. SD/MMC Card Reader Controller (rev 01)
06:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir (rev d1)
06:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 1637
06:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
06:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir USB 3.1
06:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir USB 3.1
06:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor (rev 01)
06:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
```

Update:

```
$ grep -i "key_.*camera" /lib/udev/hwdb.d/*

/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb: KEYBOARD_KEY_95=camera                                 # Shutter button - Takes a picture if optional camera available
/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb: KEYBOARD_KEY_8b=camera
/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb: KEYBOARD_KEY_090015=camera                             # Fn+F6 headset/camera VoIP key  ??
/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb: KEYBOARD_KEY_f1=camera                                 # BIOS toggles camera power
/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb: KEYBOARD_KEY_c1002=camera          # Webcam button
/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb: KEYBOARD_KEY_c1013=camera          # Webcam button
/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb: KEYBOARD_KEY_c1007=camera    # Webcam button
/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb: KEYBOARD_KEY_c100e=images      # Camera icon, "Photo Gallery"
/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb: KEYBOARD_KEY_90005=camera
/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb: KEYBOARD_KEY_c1005=camera
/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb: KEYBOARD_KEY_0c01b6=camera
/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb: KEYBOARD_KEY_90002=camera       # webcam
/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb: KEYBOARD_KEY_ee=camera                                 # Fn+F6 camera disable
/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb: KEYBOARD_KEY_f9=camera
/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb: KEYBOARD_KEY_f8=sound                                  # Fn+CAMERA = Mic
/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb: KEYBOARD_KEY_f6=camera                                 # Fn+T
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't dismiss the "camera key" option so easily. Maybe you do have one, but you don't know about it:

```
grep -i "key_.*camera" /lib/udev/hwdb.d/*
```

Now, just because a key code is defined there that doesn't mean that you actually have such a key. But you can test that with `xev` from the *x11-utils* package.

Also, some Lenovo laptops have other key combinations to make up for the lack of some Fn+?? keys. Check here:

- http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_get_special_keys_to_work
- https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/ACPI/ThinkPad-special-buttons

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I find out if the keys exist on my keyboard?

Comment: Like I wrote above: Start `xev` from a terminal window, punch keys and watch the messages what the key names are.

Comment: I added the output for the grep command - See below "Update". I've tried to find one the codes from the output but I didn't find any of these with the xev tool. Also I can't test key combinations. Does any of them look to you as it would be an actual key on my keyboard? I don't think it is one of the function key ones because I don't have a camera function key, and the mentioned ones all have a different function like increasing monitor brightness or mute the mic